# Why is the dimension of a crystallographic group unique?

Tags: group-theory, crystallography

The algebraic definition of a crystallographic group goes as follows:

If a group $\Gamma$ fits into a short exact sequence
$$0 \to \mathbb{Z}^n \overset{i}{\to} \Gamma \overset{p}{\to} G \to 1$$
such that $i \left(\mathbb{Z}^n \right)$ is maximal abelian in $\Gamma$ and $G$ is finite, then $\Gamma$ is a crystallographic group. In this case, $n$ is called the dimension of $\Gamma$ and $G$ is called the holonomy group of $\Gamma$.

Why is the dimension of a crystallographic group unique? I guess it has something to do with $i \left(\mathbb{Z}^n \right)$ being maximal abelian, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Your question is equivalent to proving that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ cannot contain $\mathbb{Z}^m$ with finite index, unless $m=n$. Can you see why this is equivalent (and why this is a promising route)?

Comment: Yes, I see! I hadn't thought of it that way yet. Thank you!

Comment: No problem. If it helped, I'll put it as a "hint" answer.

Comment: This solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint.** Your question is equivalent to proving that $\mathbb{Z}^n$ cannot contain $\mathbb{Z}^m$ with finite index, unless $m=n$.